# Google Vision API for Detecting Document throwing error when trying to access confidence of block

Tags: python-3.x, image-segmentation, google-vision

Hi I'm using the below code which I got from here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-fulltext :

```
def detect_document(path):
    """Detects document features in an image."""
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)

    for page in response.full_text_annotation.pages:
        for block in page.blocks:
            print('\nBlock confidence: {}\n'.format(block.confidence))

            for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
                print('Paragraph confidence: {}'.format(
                    paragraph.confidence))

                for word in paragraph.words:
                    word_text = ''.join([
                        symbol.text for symbol in word.symbols
                    ])
                    print('Word text: {} (confidence: {})'.format(
                        word_text, word.confidence))

                    for symbol in word.symbols:
                        print('\tSymbol: {} (confidence: {})'.format(
                            symbol.text, symbol.confidence))
```

When I run this code on a textimage: I get this error:
    ----> 1 detect_document('test.png')

```
<ipython-input-27-7dd18fd183a0> in detect_document(path)
     12     for page in response.full_text_annotation.pages:
     13         for block in page.blocks:
---> 14             print('\nBlock confidence: {}\n'.format(block.confidence))
     15 
     16             for paragraph in block.paragraphs:

AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'confidence'
```

None of the attributes like block, paragragh, word, symbol has a confidence attribute.